# Session variables not propagating

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

I have set up a standard ASP.NET Webforms application on my PC. The login pages stores 3 session variables; a username, password and redirect.

From what I've seen, I can use `Session["user"] = username` or `Session.Add("user", username);` to set the variables.

Once the variables have been set, I redirect to another page which performs some further authentication checks.

In the receiving page, I have the following

```
protected void Page_Load(object s, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      var user = (string)(Session["user"]);
   } 
}
```

When I come to look at user though, it is null.

Everything on my set up are the out of the box values.

Further info

In my caller, the session is set like this

```
 if (user.UserName == "admin")
 {
     Session.Add("user", UserName.Text);
     Session.Add("pass", Password.Text);
     Session.Add("redir", Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
     Response.Redirect("SecondPage.aspx", false);
 }
```

In my SecondPage.aspx

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ReturnUrl = (string)(Session["redir"]);
        Username = (string)(Session["user"]);
        Password = (string)(Session["pass"]);
    }
```

(ReturnUrl, Username and Password are just simple get;set properties)

** Additional

Just to make sure I'm not losing my marbles, I've performed two additional tests.

First I added in to the Page_Load for the first page the following

```
Session["fish"]="chips";
```

I then read that back in within Page2 and "chips" shows.

Next I created a static class and assigned the properties of the class and tried to read that in within Page 2 - all of them were null despite them being set (and tested) before the redirect to page2.

This has got me perplexed!

Comment: How do you determine that it's null? That variable `user` only exists inside that `if` statement. If you look at a variable `user` anywhere else, that's a different variable.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this.  Can you provide a more complete example which demonstrates the problem?  I suspect the error is elsewhere.

Comment: @Guffa - I test the variable within the if (Console.WriteLine(user);)

Comment: @David - I've updated the code in the main question

Comment: Why are you storing the password in the Session? You should never store user passwords in plaintext in memory! They should be hashed, salted, and stored in a database or other data store. When a user attempts to login, you should hash that password and compare it to the stored one.

Comment: @mason - very quick proof of concept. Just need to make sure it works. It's held locally on my laptop so no-one will ever need it

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your if statement that sets the session variables is inside of a button click? Otherwise you are setting them right away to the value of empty text boxes. Simplify your code some to test to see if there is an actual issue. Put this in each Page_Load (not in !IsPostBack).

Page one

```
Session["user"] = "test user";
```

Page two

```
//set breakpoint here
var user = Session["user"].ToString();
```

That will show you if there is an actual issue or if there is just a problem with the way you are trying to use it. Also make sure your session state is set to "inproc" in your web.config file.

```
<system.web>
      <sessionState mode="InProc"
                    timeout="20"/>
      </sessionState>
</system.web>
```

Comment: The setting does occur within a button click and then only once the username has been validated. I've tried reading Session["user"] in Page2, but it comes out as null. I get the same null results if I try to set the ViewState to store the values instead of the session. In both cases, Session and ViewState are showing 3 keys.

Comment: ViewState is the wrong place for this. As Stephen Brickner said, check your web.config to make sure your session state is configure correctly.

Comment: @Nodoid ViewState is only specific to a particular instance of a page, you can't use it to share data between pages.